# Random Date & Number into DataFrame. But results are all 0s?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, dataframe, random

**Aim:**

1.Populate single col DataFrame of random numbers based on poisson distribution

2.Depending on the random number, populate that quantity of random dates between Inception & Expire Dates boundary.

3.Append into another DataFrame the random numbers & dates
***if there are 1 random date then there will be 1 column, if 2 random dates then there will be 2 column of dates etc****

**Problem: I keep getting all ZEROs..I've tried alternative random no# methods and converting date into integer then randomise it but still cant rectify it...Please help!!!**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random

InceptionDate = pd.to_datetime(dfMerged["Inception Date"])
ExpireDate = pd.to_datetime(dfMerged["Expire Date"])

#A extract of the dates for your reference if need
Name: Inception Date, Length: 40081, dtype: datetime64[ns]
0       2000-01-02
1       2000-01-08
2       2000-01-03
3       2000-01-08
4       2000-01-11
5       2000-01-05
6       2000-01-07
7       2000-01-04
...      ......
#A extract of the dates for your reference if need
Name: Expire Date, Length: 40081, dtype: datetime64[ns]
0       2001-01-02
1       2001-01-08
2       2001-01-03
3       2001-01-08
4       2001-01-11
5       2001-01-05
6       2001-01-07
7       2001-01-04
...      ......

L=0.08
PolicyCount = 40081
Claim_Random_Date = []
Claim_Random_Number = []

for row in range(1, PolicyCount):
    ClaimCount = np.random.poisson(L, 1)

    if ClaimCount == 0:
        Claim_Random_Date.append(ClaimCount)
        Claim_Random_Number.append(ClaimCount)

    else:
        for x in range(1, ClaimCount.shape[0]):
            Claim_Date_Random = random.uniform(InceptionDate, ExpireDate)

            Claim_Random_Date.append(Claim_Date_Random)
            Claim_Random_Number.append(ClaimCount)
########################
###Current Result###
print(pd.DataFrame(Claim_Random_Date))    
       0
0      0
1      0
2      0
3      0
4      0
5      0
6      0
7      0
print(sum(pd.DataFrame(Claim_Random_Number)))
0
########################
###Desired Result###
print(pd.DataFrame(Claim_Random_Date)) 
             0             1
0       2000-01-02         0
1       2000-12-03    2000-09-03
2       2000-07-03         0
3       2000-08-12         0
4       2000-03-11    2000-01-29
5       2000-08-20         0
6       2000-09-30         0
7       2000-12-04         0

print(sum(pd.DataFrame(Claim_Random_Number)))
9
```

Comment: Please provide code that can be run by others. Namely, declaring the variables you use on your code.

Comment: @mcard Sorry about that!!

Comment: @mcard PLEASE NOTE: Variables are  L = 0.08 & PolicyCount=40081